# Borrar fila de table en ASP CORE usando JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Vengo con una duda , al parecer estoy planteando o ejecutando mal mi código que si tengo mas de una fila en mi tabla lo elimina completamente, cuando lo que necesito es eliminar la fila en cuestion que selecciono.

```
function BorrarFilaPresupuesto(event) {
try {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("td").closest('tr').remove();
    console.log("Fila Eliminada");
    var total_col = 0;
    $("#tblTratamiento tbody").find("tr").each(function (i, el) {

        //Voy incrementando las variables segun la fila ( .eq(0) representa la fila 1 )     
        total_col += parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(10).text());
    });
    $("#SUB_TOT_PRE").val(total_col);
    var tot1 = document.getElementById("SUB_TOT_PRE").value
    var pordscto = document.getElementById("POR_DSCTO_PRE").value
    var tot2 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").value;
    var portarj = document.getElementById("POR_TAR_PRE").value
    var tot3 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").value;
    tot2 = (tot1 * (pordscto / 100)).toFixed();
    tot3 = ((tot1 - tot2) * (portarj / 100)).toFixed();
    $("#TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").val(tot2);
    $("#TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").val(tot3);
    console.log(tot1, tot2, tot3);
    var suma = parseInt(tot1) - parseInt(tot2) + parseInt(tot3);
    $("#TOT_PAG_PRE").val(suma);
    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

}

El codigo de mi button

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light" onclick="BorrarFilaPresupuesto(event)">ELIMINAR</button></td>
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder eliminar una fila en concreto antes debes de saber cuál es la fila que quieres eliminar, ya sea marcándola (con una clase, por ejemplo) o enviando el índice al método `BorrarFilaPresupuesto`. Yo me decantaría por la primera opción, que sería algo asi:

```js
// Este evento marca la fila seleccionada al hacer 'click' sobre ella.
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {

  $('tr').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');

});

// Este evento comprueba si hay alguna fila seleccionada y la elimina.
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function() {

    let rowSelected = $('tr.selected');
  
  if (rowSelected.length === 0)
    alert('No row selected');
  else
        $('tr.selected').remove();

});
```

```css
table {
  border:solid 1px black;
}

tr.selected {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>

<button id="btnDelete">Delete row</button>
```

Como puedes ver, es un ejemplo bastante básico, pero se puede perfectamente extrapolar a tus necesidades.